# "Why is this book still important" vs "Why this book is still important"

Tags: grammar

Which one of the following is the correct one grammatically?

> 1. "Why ***is*** this book still important"
> 2. "Why this book ***is*** still important"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but one is a question, while the other isn't.

#### Case #1

A question is asked:

> Can you explain to me why is this book still important?

#### Case #2

No question is being asked. In this case, one could expect a colon (`:`) with an explanation on why this book is still important. Something like this:

> Jonathan explained why this book is still important: "it's just essential to learning programming"

Or in a newspaper headline:

> Ferguson explains why Manchester United is still the best football team in the world

#### All in One Example:

> So Joanna came to me and asked "Why is this book still important?" Well folks, I'm going to tell you exactly why this book is still important: Because I wrote it.

Comment: I don't think it's accurate to say that "one would expect a colon." It's much more common _not_ to use a colon, as in your newspaper headline example.

Comment: Thank you zerohedge for your excellent explanation. You made it easy to understand. Thank you.

Comment: @kramer: I changed "would" to "could" because while I think a colon is expected in many cases (especially with sentences in body text), I don't want to imply that it's a rule set in stone. You're welcome, Dory!